# redirect function doesnt work properly after submitting the form twice

Tags: javascript, php, html

I did a form validation where server checks submitted data. If data passes validation, then redirect to previous page, if not, a modal box will pop up tells user wrong username/password.

**The question is**, after user resubmit the form, redierct function doesn't work. It only works when user first time successfully input those fields. Can anyone help me with this please?

**The html code:**

```
<div id="formInfo">
    <form method="post" action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <span class="title">Sign in to urmajesty.net</span><br><br>

        <div id="input_container">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><img src="Images/icons/user.png" id="input_img"><br><br>
        </div>

        <div id="psw_container">
             <input type="password" name="psw" placeholder="password"><img src="Images/icons/key.png" id="key_img"><br><br>
        </div>

        <div id="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="RememberUsername" value="Yes"><span class="checkboxtxt">Remember my username</span>
        </div><br><br>

        <div id="Forget">
            <a href="#"><span class="forget1">Forget Password</span></a><a href="#"><span class="forget2">Forget Username</span></a>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="button" value="SIGN IN"><br><br>

        <div id="hispan"><p class="hip"><span class="hi">New to urmajesty.net?</span></p></div><br>

             <input class='disable_me' name="referer" type="hidden" value="<?php echo urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])?> " />
             <button type="button" class="button" id="btn">CREATE ACCOUNT</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id='modal_box'>
    <div class='modal_content'>
         <span class='close'>&times;</span><p>username/password is wrong. Please try again!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The php code:**

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    $validation=Login();
    if($validation==false){
        echo"<script>
        var modal_box=document.getElementById('modal_box');
        modal_box.style.display='block';    
        modal_box.style.backgroundColor='rgba(0,0,0,0.4)';
        var close=document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];
        close.onclick=function(){
            modal_box.style.display='none';
        }
        window.onclick=function(event){
            if(event.target==modal_box){
                modal_box.style.display='none';
            }
        }
        </script>";
    }
    else{
        if(!empty($_POST['referer']) && !is_array($_POST['referer'])){
            header("Location: ".urldecode($_POST['referer']));
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: window.location = $_POST['referer'];

Comment: @manikantgautam sorry, but I doubt I can use javascript and php together?

Comment: you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to redirect.

```
if(!empty($_POST['referer']) && !is_array($_POST['referer'])){ ?>
    //header("Location: ".urldecode($_POST['referer']));
    <script>
        window.location.href = "<?=$_POST['referer']?>";
    </script>
 <?php
    exit();
 } ?>
```

Comment: I'm getting a 'Access forbidden!' error... pls help

Comment: are you sure you are redirecting to the proper page? please check the URL in `$_POST['referer']`

Comment: The problem is still there... Maybe I didn't explain clearly... let's assume user input the wrong password first time, and modal box shows up, after close the box, user refilled the filelds, and this time he passed the validation but the page still stay on the login form, yet not redirect to the previous page. And I checked the url, it turned out to be the login page's url in the second time.. Is there anyway to redirect user to the previous page even if he submit several times wrong information??

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using `header()` to redirect, you can use meta refresh method, or JS `window.location` method.

```
  <script>
     window.location = "<?=$_POST['referer']?>"
  </script>
```

Comment: I tried your way and instead, I'm getting a 'Access forbidden!' error... pls help

Comment: Access forbidden is other thing rather than page redirect.

Comment: ok I fixed it, that was a syntax error. The problem is still there... Maybe I didn't explain clearly... let's assume user input the wrong password first time, and modal box shows up, after close the box, user refilled the filelds, and this time he passed the validation but the page still stay on the login form, yet not redirect to the previous page...